# Implementing Interfaces with Generics in Jooq

Tags: java, generics, jooq

I have several dozen generated JOOQ tables representing views in my MySQL database, all with matching columns. I want to operate on these views generically - so I used a [generator strategy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/) below to implement Interfaces guaranteeing underlying fields:

```
<strategy>
  <matchers>
    <tables>
      <table>
        <expression>V_.*_TO.*</expression>
        <tableImplements>MyView</tableImplements>
        <recordImplements>MyRecord</recordImplements>
      </table>
    </tables>
  </matchers>
</strategy>
```

Here's what my interfaces look like:

```
public interface MyView<R extends TableRecord> extends Table<R> {
    default TableField<MyRecord, Integer> get_MY_RECORD_COLUMN() {
        return (TableField<MyRecord, Integer>) this.field("my_record_column");
    }
...
}
```

```
public interface MyRecord<R extends UpdatableRecord<R>> extends UpdatableRecord<R> {
    public void setMyRecordColumn(Integer value);
...
}
```

Here's what JOOQ generates:

```
public class VMyGeneratedView extends TableImpl<VMyGeneratedRecord> implements MyView {
...
}
```

```
public class VMyGeneratedRecord extends TableRecordImpl<VMyGeneratedRecord> implements MyRecord, Record8<Integer, Integer, Integer, String, Integer, Integer, Integer, String> {
...
}
```

I had my interfaces extend `TableRecord` / `Table` above to access the underlying fields. Since both `MyView` and `TableImpl` implement an underlying `Table`, their generic arguments MUST match (same problem for `MyRecord`).

The generated tables will only work if I hand edit like so:

```
public class VMyGeneratedView extends TableImpl<VMyGeneratedRecord> implements MyView<VMyGeneratedRecord> {
...
}
```

```
public class VMyGeneratedRecord extends TableRecordImpl<VMyGeneratedRecord> implements MyRecord<VMyGeneratedRecord>, Record8<Integer, Integer, Integer, String, Integer, Integer, Integer, String> {
...
}
```

How do I configure JOOQ to inject the generics I need? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it would be possible to implement an elaborate mapping between XML configuration and implied generics (after all, if you declare your interface to have a `<R>` type variable, that's *"probably"* the `Record` type), this isn't being done:

1. It seems brittle and incomplete. Very quickly, additional edge cases arise that wouldn't be covered, and this would quickly turn into a maintenance nightmare
2. You probably don't actually need the generic type on your interface
3. If you really do, you can still implement a [programmatic generator strategy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/), where you're in full control of the exact string being generated for those super types.

A bit more info on 2), you don't need the generic type on your interface. Just declare them like this:

```java
public interface MyView {
    default Field<Integer> get_MY_RECORD_COLUMN() {
        return (Field<Integer>) this.field("my_record_column");
    }
...
}
public interface MyRecord {
    public void setMyRecordColumn(Integer value);
...
}
```

The interfaces will be mixed in to your generated code. This should be good enough for most cases, I would think?

Comment: Thank you for replying!  
1. I've completed the code for reading the views (python script fixed the generics  temporarily). There were edge cases involving casting, but it works.  
2. Unfortunately this does not work - I already tried doing this since this was the pattern I've seen you use in other responses, but Java des not recognize this.field() without inheriting org.jooq.Fields. The compiler now yells at me:  
```
cannot find symbol  
  symbol: method field(String)  
```
3.
I did start looking into this. I don't have an org.jooq.codegen package. Guessing there's an add-on library?

Comment: @Nickdom1: I mean, you can just cast `((Table<?>) this)` in your implementation.

Comment: @LukasElder wow I can't believe I didn't think of that! Guess I'm just rusty. I had to refactor my queries and interface to use things like .asTable() but otherwise that works great!    Do you know if I can still use the UpdatableRecord feature this way?

Comment: @Nickdom1: What does this mean: "use the UpdatableRecord feature this way". Perhaps worth a new question?

Comment: @LukasElder sorry, I meant if I can still update underlying fields in the Record since my underlying Record classes extend UpdatableRecordImpl. I can open a new question if I run into problems implementing your solution - thank you so much!